# Problems linking boost + my own .lib statically in MSVC10

Tags: c++, boost, dll, linker

I have an MFC application that links statically to a library I wrote, and I also use boost in both projects (1.51).

Using dynamically linked runtimes and boost libs (my library is statically linked), all seems to work well.

However I was keen to make a statically linked version so I can easily distribute the .exe to some colleagues.  I understand I can probably just revert to dynamically linked and use an MSI, etc. but I want to understand what's going on with my problem...

So I got it to compile eventually, but not without LN4049 warnings such as these:

```
MyLib.lib(MyModule.obj) : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol _printf imported
```

The MSDN documentation suggests this is due to dll export/import declarations, but there are none of these in my code at least, and I can't see where else they would be coming from.

Before I got it to compile successfully, I was having lots of linker errors relating to DLL import libraries (symbol conflicts / redeclarations):

```
1>boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.lib(boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.dll) : error LNK2005: "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::system_category(void)" (?system_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) already defined in libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib(error_code.obj) 
1>boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.lib(boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.dll) : error LNK2005: "class boost::system::error_category const & __cdecl boost::system::generic_category(void)" (?generic_category@system@boost@@YAABVerror_category@12@XZ) already defined in libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib(error_code.obj)
```

etc. and I had to ignore these DLL import libraries:

```
MSVCRTD.lib, msvcprtd.lib, & boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.lib
```

I understand these are the import libraries for DLL linking.  The BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC output happily reports all the static boost libs I'm linking against, and it includes boostlib_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.lib (for both the library build and the executable):

```
1>  MyModule.cpp
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_thread-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_system-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib
1>  Linking to lib file: libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-sgd-1_51.lib
```

I can't see anywhere in my project configurations where I'm asking for DLL linkage.

I've checked the run-time library choices (multi-threaded debug, statically linked).  I'm using MFC in a static library, and all the boost libraries are available (and I've not declared the BOOST_DYNAMIC_etc flag anywhere).

I'm just struggling to think of where else I might have messed up the config, or whether there is some gotchya using these libraries that precludes static linking (or at least without generating those LNK4049 warnings).

Any ideas?

Here are my command line options for compiler/linker on both projects..

Application Compiler:

```
/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC" /D "_GUICON" /D "WIN32" /D "_WINDOWS" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MTd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Yu"StdAfx.h" /Fp"Debug_Static\MyApp.pch" /Fa"Debug_Static\" /Fo"Debug_Static\" /Fd"Debug_Static\vc100.pdb" /FR"Debug_Static\" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue
```

Application Linker:

```
/OUT:"C:\VSPRJ10\MyApp\Debug_Static\MyApp.exe" /VERBOSE:Lib /INCREMENTAL:NO /NOLOGO /LTCG:STATUS "MyLib.lib" "setupapi.lib" /NODEFAULTLIB:"MSVCRTD.lib" /NODEFAULTLIB:"msvcprtd.lib" /NODEFAULTLIB:"boost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_51.lib" /MANIFEST /ManifestFile:"Debug_Static\MyApp.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ALLOWISOLATION /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /DEBUG /PDB:"C:\VSPRJ10\MyApp\Debug_Static\MyApp.pdb" /MAP /MAPINFO:EXPORTS /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /PGD:"C:\VSPRJ10\MyApp\Debug_Static\MyApp.pgd" /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /ERRORREPORT:QUEUE
```

Library compiler:

```
/ZI /nologo /W3 /WX- /Od /Oy- /D "_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501" /D "BOOST_LIB_DIAGNOSTIC" /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_LIB" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm /EHsc /RTC1 /MTd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Debug_Static\MyLib.pch" /Fa"Debug_Static\" /Fo"Debug_Static\" /Fd"Debug_Static\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue
```

Library Libarian:

```
/OUT:"C:\VSPRJ10\MyApp\Debug_Static\MyLib.lib" /NOLOGO /VERBOSE
```

Comment: Please, go to "C/C++" page, copy and paste here the whole "Command line". Then go to "Linker" page and copy&paste it "Command line" as well.